# String passed to web service inserts Unicode escape

Tags: ios, swift, string, unicode

I have a location start and destination which come from LocationServices framework.

The address line is a Swift `String`. However, when it is passed to a service as a parameter, it goes with `\U2013` inserted.

Example:
If the string is `"100198 Commerce St"`, it would be like
`"100\U2013198 Commerce St"`

`\U2013` is getting inserted and I don't have any idea from where.

Comment: Need some more information here I feel. Have you searched your project for that "\U2013" string to see if it is somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes. I have searched the entire code. But i guess this is some unicode characters issue I am unable to figure out.

Comment: \U2013 is the Unicode character for Dash -> http://www.charbase.com/2013-unicode-en-dash

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert the Unicode string to a 8-bit string. Try this function to get your required string.

```
func convertString(string: String) -> String {

    if let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii, allowLossyConversion: true) {
        return String.init(data: data, encoding: .ascii)!
    }

    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The address line has a unicode character and when you pass it to your service, it is encoded with non-unicode (probably UTF-8) encoding.

That is a broad topic, I'd suggest you looking into string encoding subject in general.